# Open file using a file name based on the current date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

I have a script that opens a file by name, but the file gets updated daily with a new name. For example the file name could be 'L661_CAD-**04-01-16**.csv' but the next day it could change to 'L661_CAD-**05-01-16**.csv'.

I would like the first part of the name to be the same `L661_CAD-` and have the date updated in the script so it looks at the most recent file.

Here is the current code I am using, it looks for the full file name:

```
var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B2lVvlNIDosoajRRMUwySVBPNVE'); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('L661_BOM-CAD_14-12-15.csv'); // latest report file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and hopefully this helps someone out

```
var date= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yy");
var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('*first part of the file name*'+ date +'.csv'); // L661_bom-cad is the first part of the file name
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this - any way that you can get the day, month and year out of a Date object will serve.

Here's a one-liner based on the Google Apps Script [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format) method:

```js
var filename = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),
                                    Session.getScriptTimeZone(),
                                    "'L661_BOM-CAD_'dd-MM-yy'.csv'");
```

If you wanted to use that to get any abitrary date's file, you could just provide the target date in the first parameter.

If you want to use "pure JavaScript" instead, you could do this:

```js
var today = new Date()
var day = today.getDay();
if (day < 10) day = '0'+day;
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
if (month < 10) month = '0'+month;
var year = today.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);

var filename = 'L661_BOM-CAD_%dd%-%mm%-%yy%.csv'
               .replace('%dd%',day)
               .replace('%mm%',month)
               .replace('%yy%',year);
```

There are plenty of other examples of for[matting dates in JavaScript,](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20format%20date) for anyone who wants to tweak this to suit their specific needs.

Comment: thank you for the response. I found the solution mentioned above.